# How to install old version of Rttf2pt in r?

Tags: r, fonts, package

My goal is to implement 'times new roman' font in all plots in R.
I got 'No FontName. Skipping' message when trying to load windows fonts, then the following error appears when trying to import from the specific folder:

```
> font_import(paths = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts")
Importing fonts may take a few minutes, depending on the number of fonts and the speed of the system.
Continue? [y/n] y
Scanning ttf files in C:\Windows\Fonts ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in which_ttf2pt1() : ttf2pt1.exe not found in path.
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file.path(p, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Version")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rttf2pt1/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

After looking for solutions, I downloaded the old version of "Rttf2pt", but still get an error that the package is not available:

```
> install.packages("D:\\Downloads\\Rttf2pt1_1.3.8.tar")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/wade3/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘D:\Downloads\Rttf2pt1_1.3.8.tar’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=English_Israel.1255    LC_MONETARY=English_Israel.1255
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Israel.1255    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] devtools_2.3.2             usethis_2.0.1              remotes_2.2.0              extrafont_0.17            
 [5] kableExtra_1.3.4           knitr_1.31                 dplyr_1.0.7                ggpubr_0.4.0              
 [9] ggplot2_3.3.3              rstatix_0.7.0              PerformanceAnalytics_2.0.4 xts_0.12.1                
[13] zoo_1.8-9                  sjPlot_2.8.9               arsenal_3.6.2              coin_1.4-1                
[17] survival_3.1-12            car_3.0-10                 carData_3.0-4              readxl_1.3.1              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
Error in x[["Version"]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'Rttf2pt1' is missing or broken
```

Comment: You can search the CRAN archives and find it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rttf2pt1). The last version is 1.3.8, dated 2020-01-10 06:30.